# showing overlay recyclerview with google maps

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, overlay

Hi i'm trying to make an app where have to show a map for places so for that in my fragment i have successfully implemented mapview in my fragment however i do not know how to implement overlay recyclerview on maps as you can see in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkhGj.jpg) so any assistance please i searched on google as well but didnt get any proper solution
here is my code for map

```
public class NearbyFragment extends Fragment {

    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    public NearbyFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nearby, container, false);
        mMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume();

        try{
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                googleMap = googleMap;

                // For showing a move to my location button
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
                LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker Title").snippet("Marker Description"));

                // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(sydney).zoom(12).build();
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `RelativeLayout` as root `ViewGroup`.

Comment: how can i do that i dont have much knowledge in this

Comment: just place a RecyclerView above Map same way as you place any other view above each other.

Comment: You might want to show you layout code so we can better assist you i.e. yourlayout.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Use a `RelativeLayout` to arrange things *relatively* so that you can place the `RecyclerView` on top of the `MapView`
It would look something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_height="match-parent"
android:layout_width="match-parent">

    <MapView
    android:layout_height="match-parent"
    android:layout_width="match-parent"/>

    <RecyclerView
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap-content"
    android:layout_width="match-parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Just wrote this off the top of my head, so forgive me if it isn't 100% syntactically correct. The